# Excel how to filter based on ( select columnA = ValueA) OR (select columnB = ValueB)

Tags: excel

For example, I have a very simple excel sheet which has the layout and info as following:

```
| Name        | English | French | Chinese | Korean |
|-------------|---------|--------|---------|--------|
| Eddie       | Y       |        |         |        |
| Raymond     | Y       |        | Y       |        |
| Celine Dion | Y       | Y      |         |        |
| Marion      |         | Y      |         |        |
```

I want to filter the rows such that all filtered persons can either speak Chinese OR English

The result will be Eddie, Raymond, Celine.

Comment: Take a look at [Advanced Filter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b#bkmk_3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your data is in a table or that you've engaged the autofilter, I would create an extra column called ChineaseOrEnglish in which i'd create an if() statement that uses OR() to place a 'Y' in the column where either English or Chinese is flagged.

You would then be able to filter on the ChineaseOrEnglish column.